# mod_rewrite www to no-www and http to https simultaneously

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have mod_rewrite in place with code I found to redirect all requests to the same URL without www.

What I'm trying to do now is configuring Apache mod_rewrite to do the following, without any wasted actions/additional redirects.

```
http:// to https://

http://www. to https://
```

I'm not familiar with it, but in pseudo code, `http(s)://(www.)domain.com` to `https://domain.com` for solely the URLs at the top level, excluding sub domains.

Answer (score 2):

You just need one rule for both conditions:

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1, I'm noticing that to preserve the url you use `%{REQUEST_URI}` a lot, with the `NE` flag, I like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to combine these operations into a single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. I tried the one above but it created a redirect loop on older browsers.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```